# cv2.warpAffine fails on higher dimension input

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I am trying to rewrite a script such that it'll be able to run on higher dimension tensor (on batches of data).

This is a function that works, though it does not support batches of center/scale:

```
def get_affine_transform(center,
                         scale,
                         rot,
                         output_size,
                         shift=np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.float32),
                         inv=0):
    if not isinstance(scale, np.ndarray) and not isinstance(scale, list):
        print(scale)
        scale = np.array([scale, scale])

    scale_tmp = scale * 200.0
    src_w = scale_tmp[0]
    dst_w = output_size[0]
    dst_h = output_size[1]

    rot_rad = np.pi * rot / 180
    src_dir = get_dir([0, src_w * -0.5], rot_rad)
    dst_dir = np.array([0, dst_w * -0.5], np.float32)

    src = np.zeros((3, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    dst = np.zeros((3, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    src[0, :] = center + scale_tmp * shift
    src[1, :] = center + src_dir + scale_tmp * shift
    dst[0, :] = [dst_w * 0.5, dst_h * 0.5]
    dst[1, :] = np.array([dst_w * 0.5, dst_h * 0.5]) + dst_dir

    src[2:, :] = get_3rd_point(src[0, :], src[1, :])
    dst[2:, :] = get_3rd_point(dst[0, :], dst[1, :])

    if inv:
        trans = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(dst), np.float32(src))
    else:
        trans = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(src), np.float32(dst))

    return trans
```

My new version of this function that gives similar output as the function above (if for example i have a batch of two bboxes, this function returns the same output as if i ran the above function separately on each bbox):

```
def get_affine_transforms(
        num_boxes,
        center,
        scale,
        rot,
        output_size,
        shift=np.array([0, 0], dtype=np.float32),
        inv=0
):
    if not isinstance(scale, np.ndarray) and not isinstance(scale, list):
        print(scale)
        scale = np.array([scale, scale])

    scale_tmp = scale * 200.0
    src_w = scale_tmp[:, 0]
    dst_w = output_size[0]
    dst_h = output_size[1]

    rot_rad = np.pi * rot / 180
    src_dir, dst_dir = [], []
    for i in range(num_boxes):
        src_dir.append(get_dir([0, src_w[i] * -0.5], rot_rad))
        dst_dir.append(np.array([0, dst_w * -0.5], np.float32))

    src = np.zeros((num_boxes, 3, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    dst = np.zeros((num_boxes, 3, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    src[:, 0, :] = center + scale_tmp * shift
    src[:, 1, :] = center + src_dir + scale_tmp * shift
    dst[:, 0, :] = [dst_w * 0.5, dst_h * 0.5]
    dst[:, 1, :] = np.array([dst_w * 0.5, dst_h * 0.5]) + dst_dir

    src[:, 2:, :] = get_3rd_points(src[:, 0, :], src[:, 1, :])
    dst[:, 2:, :] = get_3rd_points(dst[:, 0, :], dst[:, 1, :])

    trans = []
    for dst_, src_ in zip(src, dst):
        if inv:
            trans.append(cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(dst_), np.float32(src_)))
        else:
            trans.append(cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(dst_), np.float32(src_)))

    return np.array(trans)
```

Though, later in the program, the following code snippet fails because of `cv2.warpAffine` (data_numpy is an image):

```
    trans = get_affine_transforms(len(boxes), c, s, r, config.MODEL.IMAGE_SIZE)
    input = cv2.warpAffine(data_numpy,
                           trans,
                           (int(config.MODEL.IMAGE_SIZE[0]),
                            int(config.MODEL.IMAGE_SIZE[1])),
                           flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])

    input = transform(input).unsqueeze(0)
```

The failure:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((M0.type() == 5 || M0.type() == 6) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3) in warpAffine, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 2700
```

How can i call `cv2.warpAffine` so i can create higher dimension `input`s (that eventualy will be fed into a neural network).

Comment: just write that function yourself, warping isn't complicated, but probably it isn't as fast as opencv then, because that one is optimized for images (probably up to 4 channels). You could btw. split your dimensions into subsets and warp each part individually and merge again later.